# Opencv - Extracting data from in-game images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I need some help with an OpenCV project I'm working on. I'm taking images from a computer game (in this case, Fortnite), and I would like to extract different elements from them, eg. timer value, quantities of materials, health and shield etc.

Currently I perform a series of image preprocessing functions until I get a binary image, followed by locating the contours in the image and then sending those contours to a machine learning algorithm (K-Nearest-Neighbours).

I am able to succeed in a lot of cases, but there are some images where I don't manage to find some of the contours, therefore I don't find all the data.

An important thing to note is that I use the same preprocessing pipeline for all images, because I'm looking for as robust of a solution that I can manage.

I would like to know what I can do to improve the performance of my program. -

- Is KNN a good model for this sort of task, or are there other models that might give me better results?
- Is there any way to recognise characters without locating contours?
- How can I make my preprocessing pipeline as robust as possible, given the fact that there is a lot of variance in the background across all images?

My goal is to process the images as fast as possible, starting out with a minimum of at least 2 images per second.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can give me!

- [Here is an example image before preprocessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq3yo.jpg)
- [Here is the image after preprocessing,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biCgt.jpg) in this example I cannot find the contour for the 4 on the right side.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to make an ai player?

Comment: I am not trying to make an ai player. I was being a vague on purpose, also because I don't feel like sharing that information if it isn't necessary, and also because I don't see the relevance of that information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, enlarging the image might help, since it increases the dark border of the number.

I threw together some code that does that. The result could be improved, but my point here is to show that the 4 can now be detected as a contour. To increase efficiency I only selected contours within a certain size.

Also, since it is part of the HUD, that usually means that the location on screen is always the same. If so, you can get great performance increase by only selecting the area with values (described [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#image-roi)) - as I have done manually.

Finally, since the numbers have a consistent shape, you could try [matchShapes](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#match-shapes) as an alternative to kNN to recognize the numbers. I don't know how they compare in performance though, so you'll have to try that out yourself.

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
# load image
img = cv2.imread("fn2.JPG")
# enlarge image
img = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=4, fy=4, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# create mask using threshold
ret,mask = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# find contours in mask
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw contour on image
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 3000 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 200:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (255,0,0), 2)

#show images
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: That actually seems like such a simple answer, i'm pretty embarrassed I didn't think of it myself. Thank you very much! I'll check out matchShapes as well, to see the differences, but I believe enlarging the picture will be enough to solve my problem. The rest of the answer is pretty much stuff I've done/tried already, so it's good to get some confirmation on those parts.